# How to transform multiple view to same location(CGPoint)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, cgpoint

I've got multiple `UIImageView`s, spread across in a view.

```
@IBOutlet var leftIVs: [UIImageView]!
@IBOutlet var topIVs: [UIImageView]!
@IBOutlet var rightIVs: [UIImageView]!
```

I'm trying to create a function using `UIView.animate...` functions and 'transform' property which brings all of these `UIImageView`s at the center of the `superview`. I'm using the following code:

```
let performInitialTransformation: ((UIImageView)->()) = { (card) in
    let cardCenter = CGPoint(x: card.frame.midX, y: card.frame.midY)
    let viewCenter = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY)
    let deltaPoint = cardCenter - viewCenter //also tried (viewCenter - cardCenter)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        card.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: deltaPoint.x, y: deltaPoint.y)
    }) { (done) in 
    }
}

for card in topIVs {
    performInitialTransformation(card)
}

for card in leftIVs {
    performInitialTransformation(card)
}

for card in rightIVs {
    performInitialTransformation(card)
}
```

I'm using this static function:

```
extension CGPoint {
    static func -(lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: rhs.x - lhs.x, y: rhs.y - lhs.y)
    }
}
```

**NOTE: Also, I will be bringing those images back to there original position afterward** for which I will use `CGAffineTransform.identity`

The images are not being shown in the center. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the current behavior?

Comment: basically they move a little closer to the center but don't stack up at the center. Images near the left edge stack up on the left side of the center. And similarly the one on the right stack up near the top of the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem was that you didn't reduce the size of the image view so that they stack at the exact centre of the screen.

```
let deltaX = (self.view.center.x - card.frame.minX) - card.frame.width/2
let deltaY = (self.view.center.y - card.frame.minY) - card.frame.height/2
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
    card.transform = .init(translationX: deltaX, y: deltaY)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code gives me the same result I was getting with mine.

Comment: That code works perfectly on my side, could you add a visual representation of the result you're getting?

Comment: It's working fine now. Just executed the code in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewWillAppear`. It still seems strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

What is about to use `center`

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    images.forEach { $0.center = superview.center }
}
```

The full example

```
var subviewes = [UIView]()
var view = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
view.backgroundColor = .yellow
subviewes.append(view)

view = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
view.backgroundColor = .green
subviewes.append(view)

view = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
view.backgroundColor = .red
subviewes.append(view)

subviewes.forEach { self.view.addSubview($0) }

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    subviewes.forEach { $0.center = self.view.center }
}
```

Comment: This isn't possible if OP uses Auto Layout for example.

Comment: And what if I want to bring those UIImageView to their original position after some time? I don't this will be helpful with that.